# How to simplify this function and make it universal for n-level depth?

Tags: php, arrays

I seem to struggle with (for me) complex recursive functions. Could anyone point me in the right direction so that I can simplify this messy and repetitive code? Also, it's meant to work for n-level deep.

```
$hasProducts = array();

function filterOutEmpty($levelZero) {
    global $hasProducts;
    foreach ($levelZero as $levelZeroK => $levelZeroV) {
        if (empty($levelZeroV['products']) && empty($levelZeroV['families'])) continue;

        if (!empty($levelZeroV['products'])) {
            $hasProducts[$levelZeroK] = $levelZeroV;
        }

        if (!empty($levelZeroV['families'])) {
            foreach ($levelZeroV['families'] as $levelOneK => $levelOneV) {
                if (empty($levelOneV['products']) && empty($levelOneV['families'])) continue;

                if (!empty($levelOneV['products'])) {
                    $hasProducts[$levelZeroK]['families'][$levelOneK] = $levelOneV;
                }

                if (!empty($levelOneV['families'])) {
                    foreach ($levelOneV['families'] as $levelTwoK => $levelTwoV) {
                        if (empty($levelTwoV['products']) && empty($levelTwoV['families'])) continue;

                        if (!empty($levelTwoV['products'])) {
                            $hasProducts[$levelZeroK]['families'][$levelOneK]['families'][$levelTwoK] = $levelTwoV;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample input could be as follows:

```
$districts = [
    1 => [
        'id' => 1,
        'families' => [
            0 => [
                'id' => 2
            ],
            1 => [
                'id' => 3,
                'families' => [
                    0 => [
                        'id' => 2,
                        'products' => [
                            1 => 'Arnold'
                        ],
                    ],
                    1 => [
                        'id' => 2,
                        'products' => [],
                    ],
                ]
            ],
        ]
    ],
    2 => [
        'id' => 1,
        'families' => [
            0 => [
                'id' => 2,
                'products' => [
                    1 => 'John Doe'
                ],
            ],
            1 => [
                'id' => 3,
                'products' => [],
            ],
        ]
    ],
    3 => [
        'id' => 1,
        'products' => [
            1 => 'Hi',
            2 => 'Hello',
        ]
    ],
    4 => [
        'id' => 1,
        'families' => [
            0 => [
                'id' => 2
            ],
            1 => [
                'id' => 3
            ],
        ]
    ],
];
```

The desired output:

```
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [families] => Array
                (
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [families] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 2
                                            [products] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [1] => Arnold
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [families] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [products] => Array
                                (
                                    [1] => John Doe
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [products] => Array
                (
                    [1] => Hi
                    [2] => Hello
                )

        )

)
```

Please, keep in mind, that the array can be nested x-levels deep, this is just as an example. With each level I would need to add another if check (!empty($level{SOME_LEVEL}V['families'])) { ... the code again for a particular level... }

Comment: Could you explain what do you want this code to do? It might help figuring out a good way to solve this problem

Comment: An example input and output would probably help.

Comment: Thank you guys for the quick response. I've edited the question, added a sample input, and the desired output. I just want to highlight that it's a SAMPE input and can be nested more levels deep than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code uses a recursive function to parse each level, so the number of levels doesn't matter.  Each time it enters the routine it gets passed in the current level and will return the representation of that level in the new format ( I think ).

The one part is that after each recursive call, it checks if the return value is empty and only adds it in if it contains something...

```
function filterOutEmpty($levelZero) {
    $hasProducts = [];
    foreach ($levelZero as $levelZeroK => $levelZeroV) {
        if (!empty($levelZeroV['products'])) {
            $hasProducts[$levelZeroK] = $levelZeroV;
        }
        else if ( is_array($levelZeroV))  {
            $new = filterOutEmpty($levelZeroV);
            if ( !empty($new) )     {
                $hasProducts[$levelZeroK] = $new;
            }
        }
        if (!empty($levelZeroV['families'])) {
            $new = filterOutEmpty($levelZeroV['families']);
            if ( !empty($new) )     {
                $hasProducts[$levelZeroK]['families'] = $new;
            }
        }
    }
    return $hasProducts;
}

print_r(filterOutEmpty($districts));
```

Comment: Thank you a ton! I need to get my head around recursive functions, they are so useful yet they can drive me crazy.

A side note: I just realised that I had overlooked missing keys in my sample output. They can easily be put back in by adding:  unset($levelV['families']); $hasProducts[$levelK] = $levelV; $hasProducts[$levelK]['families'] = $new; in the last condition.